# How to embed a third party application (using SDL2) into a QWidget?

Tags: python, pyqt5, cross-platform, embed, sdl-2

I am trying to display another processes window inside my PyQt5 application. Since I work on Linux, I've got this [python gist](https://gist.github.com/chipolux/acf28d367822e20cc62672f49eb1aab7) working with x11. I changed the code to grab from PID instead and busy wait until the window is open and launch the program with `subprocess.Popen`
However there are a few problems with this approach:

It is somehow unstable. Sometimes it fails to grab the window, and I think it has something to do with restoring layout from `QSettings` directly on startup.
I get these error messages:

```
qt.qpa.xcb: QXcbConnection: XCB error: 3 (BadWindow), sequence: 2577, resource id: 127926283, major code: 18 (ChangeProperty), minor code: 0
qt.qpa.xcb: QXcbConnection: XCB error: 3 (BadWindow), sequence: 2578, resource id: 127926283, major code: 12 (ConfigureWindow), minor code: 0
```

What does it mean?

However I would accept an unstable solution, if it wasn't platform dependent! I would love to have a platform independent solution, at least for Linux and Windows. Using the xlib inside my PyQt5 application will tie it onto Linux I guess. So the next question is there a platform independent way to display a third party application which is using SDL2 inside my PyQt5 app? I'm not sure, but maybe it would be a solution to embed a xserver inside my application, but I don't know much about xserver and I don't think it would be an easy task.

The dream solution would be purly written in Python (or in C++ if there is no other way), but since the third party application is open source (C++), I could rewrite the application in such a way to support being plattform independently grabbed by PyQt5. It would be inconvinient, because I couldn't work with the prebuild binaries, but if that is the only way, with a reasonable amount of effort, I would take it. My instant idea was to get the window ID via SDL and send it somehow over to my application. My researches didn't yield any results on how to do that and [my attempt](https://gist.github.com/sewbacca/79a84414e73848dc1e931051643f752a) to use

```cpp
SDL_GetWindowID(SDL_Window * window);
```

failed, because soon I (think I) found out, that it returned the SDL intern window ID rather than the OSes WID. So my question here is: How do I get the Window ID from SDL? Or how to enable my PyQt5 app to grab its window?

Maybe the best (and most difficult) solution would be to rewrite the open source app in such a way to display their content inside a QWindow and sent this ID over, but I have no idea how to approach that, nor to link this app with qt. Maybe it is worth noting at this point, that I'm pretty new to Qt, that's why I am using PyQt5.

Comment: You point to: *My researches didn't yield any results on how to do that and my attempt to use ...*, could you provide a [mre] of what you point to

Comment: The minimal example I've tried is already given. `SDL_GetWindowID(SDL_Window * window);` gave back `2` on a window handle and trying to get window info using `xprop - id 2` resulted into an error. Is a reproducible example for this oneliner necessary?

Comment: No, I want a code that I can execute and reproduce

Comment: So you believe that SDL_GetWindowID should return the actual WindowID for the current Operating System? e. g. X11 WID?

Comment: yes, in C++ it works

Comment: I dont know how to generate a minimal reproducable example, so [here](https://github.com/sewbacca/winid-love) is my fork of the open source application. In the [newest commit](https://github.com/sewbacca/winid-love/commit/2fb56b446a8e2107f71498ab7a1d83a20fdac8f2) you should find the line I added to print the window ID. It still printed `2`.

Comment: It's very simple: 1) create a C ++ window that uses SDL and provide that code, 2) show the python code where you try to embed the SDL window

Comment: Since the window ID is invalid, any python code would be unecessary.
[Here](https://gist.github.com/sewbacca/79a84414e73848dc1e931051643f752a) is a short C++ gist showing the error.

Comment: So you could not put that in your post?

Comment: At the creation time I didn't thought it would be necessary (and I didn't knew how) because I believed that it doesn't give me the OSes window ID and it still doesn't give me a correct one. I added it to the post. Now, why doesn't it give me the correct window ID?

Comment: 1) You must provide the necessary code even if it does not work since that helps us to rule out other problems, 2) That is what we will find out but why do you think that this ID is not valid? Could you post the pyqt5 code that tries to use that ID?

Comment: This is how I tested if it grabs the correct window (bash):
`xprop -id <id>`
In my cases `<id>` was `2`, which is not the correct ID.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must use [`SDL_SysWMinfo`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_SysWMinfo) to obtain the id of the Window, it offers different attributes depending on the OS, for example for X11 you must use `x11.window` and for windows `win.window`:

**main.cpp**

```cpp
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_syswm.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    uint32_t nix = 0;
    auto win = SDL_CreateWindow("Test", 0, 0, 400, 200, nix);

    SDL_RaiseWindow(win);

    SDL_SysWMinfo wmInfo;
    SDL_VERSION(&wmInfo.version);
    SDL_GetWindowWMInfo(win, &wmInfo);

    printf("ID: %d\n", wmInfo.info.x11.window);
    fflush(stdout);

    while (1) { usleep(100000); }
    return 0;
}
```

```py
import os
import sys
from pathlib import Path

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

CURRENT_DIRECTORY = Path(__file__).resolve().parent


def find_id(executable):
    win_id = -1
    process = QtCore.QProcess()
    process.setProgram(executable)
    loop = QtCore.QEventLoop()

    def handle_readyReadStandardOutput():
        text = process.readAllStandardOutput().data().decode()
        _, id_str = text.split()
        nonlocal win_id
        win_id = int(id_str)
        loop.quit()

    process.readyReadStandardOutput.connect(handle_readyReadStandardOutput)
    process.start()
    loop.exec_()
    return win_id


def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    win_id = find_id(os.fspath(CURRENT_DIRECTORY / "test"))

    main_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(main_widget)

    window = QtGui.QWindow.fromWinId(win_id)
    widget = QtWidgets.QWidget.createWindowContainer(window)

    button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Close")
    button.clicked.connect(main_widget.close)

    layout.addWidget(widget)
    layout.addWidget(button)

    main_widget.show()
    app.exec_()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Finally, I could grab the Window ID, thank you very much!
There is one last question, do you know a way that doesn't require rewriting the third party application?

Comment: @Sewbacca Exactly for that is xlib and other libraries that allow to obtain the id using the libraries of the OS. If you want to work with different OS then use the native libraries of each OS and create a wrapper, that is to say something like: if is_x11: x11_native_lib.windows_id elif is_windows: windows_native_lib.windows_id. There is no library for it so you could create it.

Comment: It is seems so obvious now: If xlib can be grabbed from python to find a window, then there must be a solution for windows too. I must not been able to see the wood for all the trees. Thank you very much, your help is appreciated :)